# WP form handler not triggered by POST

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, varnish

I have a piece of code that is not working. It is a handler for POST submission. Below is the code sending data.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/calculator.php',
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

The handler - `calculator.php` looks like:

```
<?php
$parse_url = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
require_once($parse_url[0], 'wp-load');
send_email();
echo 'success';

function sendEmail() {
  ..
  wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

When `calculator.php`s is being invoked from the command line, it works fine. However, submitting the from with ajax or postman does nothing. I have a `varnish` cache in front of my server, but it should not matter. Should it?

Comment: url: '/calculator.php' was this path correct?

Comment: yes, the path is fine.

Comment: can you post the xhr body and header?

Comment: But you are using explode('wp-content' to get the script name.so it is confusing

Comment: Headers:
```Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:184
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:__atuvc=0%7C34%2C0%7C35%2C4%7C36%2C105%7C37%2C44%7C38; _ga=GA1.2.1051388021.1502790997
Host:xxxxx.com
Origin:http://xxxxx.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://xxxxx.com/calculator/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest```
returns OK.

Comment: you have set action for ajax in wordpress unless it will not work. Please check the manual https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)

Answer (score 0):

Put the calculator.php file in the root of the wordpress installation with the following changes. and use this path as your ajax url

**calculator.php**

```
<?php
require_once('wp-load.php');
send_email();
echo 'success';

function sendEmail() {
  ..
  wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Comment: tried before, and just in case now. does not help. In fact, even `die` does not have any affect.

Comment: Getting 200 status for the xhtr request?

Comment: I am not a WordPress person. Do see that for plugins there is a way to register actions with ajax admin. Don't want to learn how to wrap a plugin around that code, if that is an option. Did not write that thing, but my job is to get it working.

Comment: you need to add action for a working ajax call. You refer the manual and you don't need a plugin to do so.This link might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557755/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress