# Calling a PHP function from Javascript for Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've read probably more than 30-40 questions about it here but couldn't implement any of them. I say "couldn't" because probably I miss something or trying to make them work on wordpress have some difficulties.

- I have a button on one of the pages I have. That button is created with Shortcodes Ultimate and it can have an onclick value.

> [su_button url="#" style="flat" background="#ed2079" size="2"
>   wide="yes" icon="icon: pencil" onclick=execJS();]Click Me![/su_button]

- I have created a file named faucad.js and put it's reference to that page's *head* section. I can trigger that .js' function successfully by clicking that button.

**Content of faucad.js**

```
function execJS() {
   do_shortcode([my_shortcode cmd="take"]);
```

}

- Problem is, whatever code I wrote there, couldn't trigger a shortcode I have.
  Shortcode is created with a snippet plugin and it's like that;

> add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_array' );

It takes one attribute called "cmd" and it should be "take".

It doesn't recognize that function, can't build a bridge with wordpress;

> do_shortcode([my_shortcode cmd="take"]);

How can I access that shortcode? All I want to achieve is to trigger a shortcode on a button click.

Please tell me to tailor my question if it's complicated.

Thanks,

**UPDATE:**

If I make dataType as "json" I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null" error. If I make it as "html", I always get "Failed" message and code doesn't touch do_shortcode() function.

**JS**

```
function gxfd_claim() {
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "json",
            url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
            data : {action: "gxfd_claim_function"},
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.type == "success") {
                    alert("Success!")
                }
                else {
                    alert("Failure!")
                }
            }
                })
                    })
}
```

**PLUGIN'S PHP**

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_gxfd_claim_function', 'gxfd_claim_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_gxfd_claim_function', 'gxfd_claim_function');
function gxfd_claim_function() {
    do_shortcode('[gx_faucad cmd="claim"]');
    die();
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );
function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_register_script( "faucad", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/gx-internal/faucad.js', array('jquery') );
   wp_localize_script( 'faucad', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));        

   wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'faucad' );
}
```

Comment: *Calling a PHP function from Javascript...* the short answer is, you can't. PHP runs on the server and JavaScript the client machine... you can sort of work around it with Ajax.

Comment: it's not possible to call PHP directly in Javascript. You could use an AJAX request to access a PHP function. There is a few question here about that [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557755/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress).

Comment: I can't seem to make it work. I've added whole code content to my original post. Please check when you are able.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
success: function(response) {
   if(response.type == "success") {
      alert("Success!")
   }
   else {
      alert("Failure!")
   }
}
```

to

```
success: function(response, status) {
   alert(status);
}
```

The `success` function is passed these arguments, according to [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
(Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)
```

What might be happening is that the PHP script returns no data, so the `data` (`response`) parameter is `null`, and it throws the TypeError when you try to access `type` from the null parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can get success message but still, it doesn't touch do_shortcode() function in that .php.

Update: and jQuery I think is JQMigrate 1.4.1 as wordpress' default.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough experience with Wordpress to debug that part