# Wordpress Admin Ajax 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have used Wordpress Admin Ajax and the console shows that 400 (Bad Request)

```
    jQuery('#submitid').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: {status: 'status', name: 'name'},
        success:function(data){
             jQuery("#result").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You can a great answer here [WordPress Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557755/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress)

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291301/400-bad-request-on-admin-ajax-php-only-using-wp-enqueue-scripts-action-hook

Comment: did you add an action ?

Comment: This is not a question. Please read up on how to [Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Wordpress AJAX process has some basic points that should be followed if you want it to work correctly:

1.In functions.php add the action you'd like to call from the frontend:

```
function logged_in_action_name() {
  // your action if user is logged in
}
function not_logged_in_action_name() {
  // your action if user is NOT logged in
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_logged_in_action_name', 'logged_in_action_name' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_not_logged_in_action_name', 'not_logged_in_action_name' );
```

2.Register the localization object in functions.php

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$some_object = array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
);

wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'ajax_object', $some_object );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

3.Create the AJAX request on the frontend

```
// source: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins
var data = {
  'action': 'not_logged_in_action_name',
  'whatever': 1234
};

jQuery.post( ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function( response ) {
  console.log( response );
}
```

Comment: Note: If you keep your ajax logic outside of functions.php file, don't forget to require the file in functions.php.

Answer (score 2):

All Wordpress Ajax call must have `action` param which points to hook `wp_ajax_{action_param}` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{action_param}` and from there you jump to function from that hooks.

From [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins):

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action' );

function my_action() {
    $status = $_POST['status'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you shouldn't write the url by yourself. You could use the localize function to add the url to your javascript file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('myHandle','pathToJS');

wp_localize_script(
   'myHandle',
   'ajax_obj',
    array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
);
```

After this you can use `ajax_obj.ajax_url` within your script to receive the url.

Second, did you implement the correct hook?

```
// Only accessible by logged in users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
// Accessible by all visitors
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback' );
```

Best Regards