# How to get Wordpress post filter (misha_filter_function) to filter CPT categories associated by a tag

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, filter

Edited for Clarity:

I'm using the misha_filter_function from: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-post-filters.html to filter posts.

The initial array is displaying the correct posts by the location_and_season (made with ACF) tag. But something weird is going on with the second array because when I click my dropdown select to sort the posts by category it's filtering all of the posts within the post type, and effectively ignoring 'tag' => $value,

I'm relatively new to Wordpress PHP and JS, so my Google-Fu hasn't been too helpful since I don't really know what to search. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here's the filter Code:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function'); // 
wp_ajax_{ACTION HERE}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'misha_filter_function');

function misha_filter_function()
{
$value = get_field('location_and_season');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shows',
    'tag' => $value,
    'posts_per_page' => - 1, // show all posts.
    'orderby' => 'name', // we will sort posts by name
    'order' => 'ASC'
    //$_POST['name'] // ASC or DESC

);

// for taxonomies / categories
// IMPORTANT! Adding && !empty( $_POST['categoryfilter'] ) fixes the no posts found for All Categories
if (isset($_POST['categoryfilter']) && 
!empty($_POST['categoryfilter'])) $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'id',
        'terms' => $_POST['categoryfilter']
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
// The Query
query_posts($args);

// The Loop
while (have_posts()):
    the_post(); ?>
```

Here's the front end dropdown code:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" 
method="POST" id="filter" style="float:right; margin-right: 15px;">

<?php
if ($terms = get_terms(array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'orderby' => 'name'
))):

echo '<select name="categoryfilter"><option id="refresh" value="all" 
class="dropdown-select">All Topics...</option>';

foreach ($terms as $term):
    echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . 
   '</option>'; 

endforeach;
echo '</select>';
endif;
?>
<div class="processing" style="height:30px;"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
</form>
```

And the JS

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#filter').change(function () {
    var filter = $('#filter');
    $.ajax({
        url: filter.attr('action'),
        data: filter.serialize(), // form data
        type: filter.attr('method'), // POST
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            filter.find('.processing').html('<img src="spinner.gif" class="spinner">'); // changing the button label
        },
        success: function (data) {
            filter.find('.processing').text(''); // changing the button label back
            $('#response').html(data); // insert data

        }

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#filter').on("click", function () {
            $('.post-section').toggleClass("active");
        });
    });


    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything that actually calls your php function. Wordpress ajax calls require an action in the data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: filter.attr('action'),
    type: filter.attr('method'), // POST
    data: {
         action: 'misha_filter_function',
         categoryfilter:  $(select['name ="categoryfilter"]').val()
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        filter.find('.processing').html('<img src="spinner.gif" class="spinner">'); // changing the button label
    },
    success: function (data) {
        filter.find('.processing').text(''); // changing the button label back
        $('#response').html(data); // insert data
    }, 
    failure: function(response){
        console.log(response); //Debug only
    }
});
```

Also, do you enqueue the js script with [wp_localize_script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557755/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think there's something built into my starter theme, underscores, that is calling ajax. My js file is using the standard "wp_enqueue_script", but everything seems to be working fine. The filter works properly when I'm using it to filter posts by category, but now I need it to only include posts with the tag I defined here: 'tag' => $value,.