# How can i get my wordpress plugin to show where i want it to?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I made a PHP code that tracks packages by getting information from a JSON file and I turned it as a Wordpress plugin. but every time I search the outcome appears on the top of the page.hw can I make it appear where I need it to?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bERlS.jpg]

```
<?php

    $url = "a url where i get my json fille";
    $code = $_POST[code];
    $data = file_get_contents("$url$code");
    $json = json_decode($data);

    echo "<table class=\"table\">";
    foreach ($json as $key => $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $key0 => $row0) {
            echo "<th>" . $key0 . " : " . $row0 . "</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: you can turn it into function and just invoke it where you need it to be

Comment: Can you show use the plugin code? Maybe it is an option to create a shortcode and in put this in a page template or the content of the page.

Comment: Where exactly do you want it to show?

Comment: You can actually just paste this code on your theme front end like in the header.php file.

Comment: I want it to appear under the search bar and I have tried just pasting the code in where I want it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use shortcodes.

1. Firstly, wrap your code in a function

```
// NB: you can name your function anything
function trackingplugin_print_table(){
    // Not part of your code, but add it just in case
    // This simply checks if user submitted anything
    if( ! $_POST['code'] ) {
       return;
    }
    $url = "a url where i get my json fille";
    $code = $_POST[code];
    $data = file_get_contents("$url$code");
    $json = json_decode($data);

    echo "<table class=\"table\">";
    foreach ($json as $key => $row) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach ($row as $key0 => $row0) {
            echo "<th>" . $key0 . " : " . $row0 . "</th>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

2. Then add the shortcode to WordPress [More Info Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/)

```
// NB: you can also name your shortcode whatever you want
add_shortcode( 'trackingplugin', 'trackingplugin_print_table' );
```

3. Then use the shortcode `[trackingplugin]` wherever you want. In this case it would be after the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make an Ajax call and load the result to a response div.

Check here for some ideas [How to call ajax in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557755/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress)

You can replace `console.log(msg);` with `jQuery('#response_div').html(msg);`