# jQuery load() not displaying echo table from php | wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, load

I'm using Wordpress and I want to display a table, which contains pictures and buttons. This table should get loaded with a jquery `load()` method and put the result into a `div`.

I get the result, which I want, but it doesn't display in the div. Just here:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdBRi.png).

When I just put, for example, a `H2` with text and without any php into the php file, then it gets displayed.

**Script**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $id = GetURLParameter('id');
    var urlGetItem = "getItems.php/?id=" + $id;
    jQuery('#load_surveys').load(urlGetItem);
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="load_surveys"></div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

include_once 'db.php';
require ('../wp-blog-header.php');

global $wpdb;
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();
$userId = $current_user->ID;

$id = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM f5_users JOIN COMPARISONFOLDER ON COMPARISONFOLDER.USER_ID = f5_users.ID JOIN ITEM ON ITEM.COMPARISONFOLDER_ID LIKE COMPARISONFOLDER.COMPARISONFOLDER_ID WHERE COMPARISONFOLDER.COMPARISONFOLDER_ID LIKE $id AND f5_users.ID LIKE $userId");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['ITEM']).'" width="500" height="auto"/></td>';
echo "<td><button type='button' onclick='deleteItem(".$row['ITEM_ID'].", $id)'>Testing Script</button></td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: That particular request displays _in red_ in your screenshot, likely meaning the response did not come with a 200 OK status code, but an HTTP error instead. So jQuery thinks loading of this resource has actually failed, and therefor it does not insert anything into the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get if you make console.log('id',$id) and console.log('url,urlGetItem)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var $id = GetURLParameter('id');
    console.log('id',$id);
    var urlGetItem = "getItems.php/?id=" + $id;
    console.log('url,urlGetItem);
    jQuery('#load_surveys').load(urlGetItem);
});
```

PHP

```php
$markup = "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Item</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$markup .= "<tr>";
$markup .='<td><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['ITEM']).'" width="500" height="auto"/></td>';
e "<td><button type='button' onclick='deleteItem(".$row['ITEM_ID'].", $id)'>Testing Script</button></td>";
$markup .= "</tr>";
}

$markup .= "</table>";
echo $markup;
```

Comment: I get: id 246 url getItems.php/?id=246

This is correct. I can access to the php file and get the correct data.

Comment: Maybe it's better if you make an ajax call.

Comment: Maybe this post will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43557755/how-to-call-ajax-in-wordpress

Comment: Idk if this will help me. Because the issue happens later or I'm wrong?